# Detect cable unplugged in Linux by using C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, tcp

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04. Is there a way to detect if the cable is unplugged by using C?
Some mentioned to use getsockopt(TCP_INFO). But I couldn't find an example about how to do it. There is some info: https://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html. But in my case, I don't have a special port to listen.

Comment: Do you mean the network cable?

Comment: I meant C language. I updated the title. Yes, I meant the network cable.

Comment: Maybe one of the errors in [`errno`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html)?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need to see if the cable was unplugged, as opposed to just knowing that the connection doesn't exist in general?

Comment: Also note that there is no real way to detect at which end a network cable was unplugged.

Comment: ..or if some tequila-sozzled Captain has just dragged his anchor through the cables:)

Comment: @MartinJames Personal experience? ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, though I have suffered from umm.. 'involuntary JCB-initiated disconnect':)  Bob the Builder also managed to chop our heavy power cables in the same trunking, presumably resulting in brown-trousers punishment from the bang.  Our UPS kept us working but, with no offsite connections, we were forced into documentation for two days:)